# Is decomposition of convex combination always feasible?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry

Given $\mu$, $\lambda_1$,...,$\lambda_{m_1}$, $\gamma_1$,...,$\gamma_{m_2}$, which are all be vectors with $N$ entries.

Define several sets as follows.

$P=\left\{(p_1,...,p_{m_1})|p_i \in [0,1],\forall i,\sum_{i=1}^{m_1}p_i=1,\mu=p_1 \lambda_1+...+p_{m_1}\lambda_{m_1}\right\}$.

$Q=\left\{(q_1,...,q_{m_2})|q_j \in [0,1],\forall j,\sum_{j=1}^{m_2}q_j=1,\mu=q_1 \gamma_1+...+q_{m_2}\gamma_{m_2}\right\}$.

$R_i=\left\{(r_{i1},...,r_{im_2})|r_{ij} \in [0,1],\forall j,\sum_{j=1}^{m_2}r_{ij}=1,\lambda_i=r_{i1} \gamma_1+...+r_{im_2}\gamma_{m_2}\right\}$

**The question is whether the following statement is ture:**

If $P \neq \emptyset$, $Q \neq \emptyset$, $R_i \neq \emptyset$, $\forall i$, then for any $(p_1^*,...,p_{m_1}^*) \in P$ and any $(q_1^*,...,q_{m_2}^*) \in Q$, there always exist $(r_{i1}^*,...,r_{im_2}^*) \in R_i$ for each $i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m_1} p_i^*r_{ij}^*=q_j^*$, $\forall j=1,...m_2$.

When $\gamma_1$,...,$\gamma_{m_2}$ are affine independent, $Q$ is a one-element set so the above statement is true. But I am wondering what if we drop this condition.

I really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is No.

Let $N=1$. $\mu=0.5$, $\lambda_1=\gamma_1=0$, $\lambda_2=\gamma_2=0.5$, $\lambda_3=\gamma_3=1$.
One of the elements of $P$ is $(0.4,0.2,0.4)$, so $P \neq \varnothing$.
One of the elements of $Q$ is $(0.1,0.8,0.1)$, so $Q \neq \varnothing$.
$R_1$ has a unique element: $(1,0,0)$, so $R_1 \neq \varnothing$.
$R_2$ has a non-unique element: $(0,1,0)$, so $R_2 \neq \varnothing$.
$R_3$ has a unique element: $(0,0,1)$, so $R_3 \neq \varnothing$.

Choose $(p_1^*,p_2^*,p_3^*)$ to be $(0.4,0.2,0.4)$ and $(q_1^*,q_2^*,q_3^*)$ to be $(0.1,0.8,0.1)$. $R_1$ has only one element so $r_{11}^*$ must be 1. But then $p_1^*r_{11}^*=0.4>q_1^*=0.1$. Since $p_2^*$, $p_3^*$, $r_{21}^*$, $r_{31}^*$ are all non-negative, it is impossible to have $\sum_{i=1}^3 p_{i}^*r_{i1}^*=q_1^*$.